# Google Spreedsheet Maths sum -- freeze cell location so it will always stay still

Tags: google-sheets

It is driving me nuts. I just cant get it to copy the same function over and over again

```
In D4 i have 40%

in A1 i have 0.35
In A2 I want =A1+D4
```

but when I drag it down

```
it goes D5,D6,D7,D8,D8,D9 ETC
```

I want D4 to ALWAYS STAY STILL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use `$D$4`, as in

```
 A2 = A1+$D$4
```

It's called an 'absolute cell reference'.

Comment: +1 I've always used `formula("D4")` - I had no idea this existed. Can you do e.g. $d4 and d$4 too?